# Permission issue Python 3.4 apache

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, ubuntu

im have FLASK app with 
www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/**init**.py file with funtion
python file wut next contains

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    file = open('myfile.txt', 'w+')
    os.mknod("newfile.txt")
    return render_template('page2.html')
```

but if im run site,its return error, in file log write

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myfile.txt'

im set permision 777 for all www directories
open FileZilla
right click on www dir, and set 777 permision
Why file dont create?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even mention 'myfile.txt'. So that error message is impossible. Please post the minimal amount of code you can use to actually reproduce the issue. Along with the output of "ls -la" on the file in question.

Comment: edit, can be  file = open('myfile.txt', 'w+')

Comment: What is the output of this: os.getcwd() in that function?

Comment: I am not an expert on Flask, but I feel like it is trying to create that file in the root directory, as a test, try putting the absolute path in the open method and seeing if that works: i.e. `file = open('/www/myfile.txt', 'w+')`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an optimal solution, and I don't know enough about Flask as to tell you why the relative path isn't working (I would think that it would write the file where ever your python script was) but you could get it to work by using an environment variable to specify where to store your apps data. For instance:

```
import os

@app.route('/')
def open_file():
    filename = os.path.join(os.environ['FLASK_APP_DATA'], 'myfile.txt')
    print (filename)
    file = open(filename, 'w+')
    file.write("This is a test")
    file.close()
```

Then you could have the environment variable set differently on your dev box and your prod box.